# startactivty intent not work with error SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name

Tags: android, android-activity, android-ndk

I'm trying to use 3rd party library in android which has PaymentActivity starting to make a payment

here is the code :

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);//Checkout activity
            DPSettings dpSettings = new DPSettings();
            intent.putExtra(PaymentConstants.TRANSACTION_URL, "");
            intent.putExtra(PaymentConstants.PLATFORM_TYPE, dpSettings.getPlatformType());
            intent.putExtra(PaymentConstants.TRANSACTION_BLOCK, "");
            intent.putExtra(PaymentConstants.PAYMENT_FIELD_BLOCK, "");
            intent.putExtra(PaymentConstants.BILLING_BLOCK, "");
            intent.putExtra(PaymentConstants.SHIPPING_BLOCK, "");
            intent.putExtra(PaymentConstants.OTHER_DETAILS_BLOCK, "");
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    });


}
```

but when I run the application and click on the button to start the activity there is no action but in the logcat I find this message :

```
2019-07-31 10:02:58.308 1600-6058/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=porter.aia.com.paymenttesting/dp.toml.directpay.PaymentActivity (has extras)} from uid 10082
2019-07-31 10:03:00.639 1412-1412/? D/SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing porter.aia.com.paymenttesting/dp.toml.directpay.PaymentActivity to porter.aia.com.paymenttesting/dp.toml.directpay.PaymentActivity#1
2019-07-31 10:03:00.879 1600-1614/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{2e58915 u0 porter.aia.com.paymenttesting/dp.toml.directpay.PaymentActivity t609 f}
```